# visual studio emulator problem! icannot open emulator

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, android-emulator

i can't open emulator in visual studio
[image]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1jWfc.png)
[image]

Comment: C:\flutterr\game-up-to-sky\android\app\src\debug\AndroidManifest.xml Error:
 uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 19 declared in library [:cloud_firestore] C:\flutterr\game-up-to-sky\build\cloud_firestore\intermediates\merged_manifest\debug\AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
 Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
  or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 19,
  or use tools:overrideLibrary="io.flutter.plugins.firebase.firestore" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

Comment: <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.game_up_to_sky">
    <!-- The INTERNET permission is required for development. Specifically,
         the Flutter tool needs it to communicate with the running application
         to allow setting breakpoints, to provide hot reload, etc.
    -->
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
</manifest> where should i change

Comment: i added a picture

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even if you work with **Visual Studio Code**, you'll probably need **Android Studio** to create and install Virtual devices using the **Virtual Device Manager** that comes with it, to create your Virtual machines.

The Emulator configuration might be harder on some devices, depending on how easy is to set up GPU Acceleration for Virtual Devices. Some laptops actually don't allow this.

**The alternative**, is just connect your android phone or tablet to the computer with a USB cable, activate **developer mode** on your mobile device to enable the installation of **apk** packages from your computer, and if everything is OK, you'll be able to compile and run your app directly in your phone.

You can use the `flutter doctor`, to check if your installation is OK.
Notice that you don't need to install all the packages nominated by Flutter Doctor, like the Windows SDK, if you just want to create mobile apps.

Comment: i added a picture

Answer (score 1):

Go-to: C:\flutterr\game-up-to-sky\android\app\build.gradle file

Replace this line:

```
minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
```

With:

```
minSdkVersion 19
```

Comment: defaultConfig {
        (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.game_up_to_sky"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion flutter.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    } what shoulld i do? where should i change

Comment: Try looking for "minSdkVersion" (near line no. 50) change their value from flutter.minSdkVersion to 19.

Comment: i added a picture

Comment: I can understand, all you need to do is replace a line in "build.gradle" file.